# Why does a DataGridView have no properties? (C# Windows Forms, MS Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I have a Windows Form application in which my form uses a tab page control. I just added new tab page to it, and put a DataGridView control onto the new page.  When I select the control and look at my Properties tab, it's blank!  Why is this happening?  I have not set any data source for the control because I am going to be hooking it to a LINQ query object at run time.

Thanks for your help!

RobR

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the cause was, but I closed VS 2008 and reopened it, and the data grid view control had its properties.